Categories in which there is a mono $A \to B$ iff there is an epi $B \to A$
Consider the property $P$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ that for two objects $A$, $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a monomorphism $A \to B$ iff there exists an epimorphism $B \to A$. Does the property $P$ have a common name? Can you give any reference?
For example, the category $\operatorname{Set}$ has property $P$ and for any field $k$, the category $k\operatorname{-Vect}$ has property $P$. On the other hand, $R\operatorname{-Mod}$ generally does not have property $P$.
Also, if a category $\mathcal{C}$ has property $P$, we can put a natural preorder on the objects of $\mathcal{C}$: $A \leq B \Longleftrightarrow \exists A \hookrightarrow B \Longleftrightarrow \exists B \twoheadrightarrow A$.

In the context of sets, this is the Partition Principle, which is a consequence of AC, but whether it is equivalent to it is open still. So this would be a "slight weakening" of internal AC in a category.

Your order is not partial in general: If $A \cong B$ then $A \leq B$ and $B \leq A$, but $A = B$ obviously need not hold. (Also, depending on your foundations you might run into size issues.)

Strictly speaking, property $P$ holds in the category of nonempty sets, not the category of all sets (as for any nonempty set $X$, there is an injection $\emptyset \to X$ but no surjection $X \to \emptyset$).

@BenSteffan Thanks. I've edited the post to say "preorder" instead of "partial order".

@Smiley1000 Also note that you don't really need your assumption to define a natural preoder via $A \leq B$ if $\exists A \hookrightarrow B$. Your condition just means that if you define a second preorder via $A \leq B$ if $\exists B \twoheadrightarrow A$, these two preorders coincide.

I have heard the related property "every epimorphism splits" termed the "axiom of choice for a category". This implies, but is probably stronger than, your property. I think at the very least Tom Leinster gave this name in his textbook
